# Seeking world city boundary map or data from OpenStreetMap DB?

Tags: openstreetmap, data

I'm seeking world city boundary data(longitude and latitude) with city name from OpenStreetMap DB.(If you have experience with other DB Please share the information to me.)
It is OK if the data is not fully accurate.

I just want to draw world city boundary in the map with city name.

Could anyone experience this kind of data?

Comment: I found some hints by searching for "export osm boundaries" in the upper right textbox here ... Success?

Comment: There a tool where you can download boundaries after login using an osm account See https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/